# how to find Payment Response URL, in Magento account?

Tags: url, payment, response, worldpay

We are configuring, a payment gateway from Worldpay to Magento our website. it says, we need to copy the value of Payment Response URL from Magento to Worldpay, 
Payment Response URL. How can i find it in Magento ?

please inform,
many thanks
sham

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to configure it manually, as Magento_Worldpay passes response URL with request in MC_callback field.
Here you can find Worldpay documentation about it http://support.worldpay.com/support/kb/bg/paymentresponse/pr5502.html